# Can you parse a RODBC query through readr?

Tags: r, database, readr

I am trying to improve my analytics script for a database and want to use a direct output from the query in my Access DB instead of outputting to a linked excel file where I refreshed it and then saved to a csv file. I can get the table into R, but I would like it parsed through readr. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried outputting to a csv straight away then using read_csv to reimport but it pulled errors on the parsing.

```
dbdata <- sqlQuery(db , "SELECT * 
                              FROM qRoutput", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Is how I currently import my query.

I would just like to parse that query output through the readr parsing function - everything being taken as characters, doubles and the class coming back as "[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should already give the output as data.frame.
May be you could try `df = sqlGetResults(db)` after your sqlQuery.

Alternatively you can go for dbplyr approach. Below is an example. This approach is valid for RODBC connections too. [Intro to dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html)

```
library(RSQLite)

# Create a db
db = dbConnect(SQLite(), "./Data/TestDB.db")

# write data to the db
dbWriteTable(db, "testtable", mtcars)

# Check whether the table is present
dbListTables(db)

# use the dplyr syntax to query
tbl(db, "testtable") %>% select(mpg, cyl)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can get the output into a data.frame but I want it parsed through readr like a read_csv function as they way it interprets fields is different to base R.

Comment: If there are no critical issues/constraints, I suppose you can easily change the data type after you fetch it. Anyway, if you can paste the sample output you are getting rightnow and what you expect, it will easier for people to help you out.

Comment: I was hoping there might be an in-built function in a package which might streamline the process but if not, thank you for taking the time to answer. The difference is purely in the way readr parses with all integers being parsed as col_double() and 0 factors.